# Различные графики условной плотности на Python и R

Tags: python, r, график, графики

Я строю график условной плотности (conditional density plot), чтобы показать связь между языком (language) и количеством проданных копий (sales) книг в датафрейме df1.

Внешний вид моих графиков на Python и R кардинально отличается.

Код на Python:

```
sns.displot(kind='kde', multiple='fill',
            data=df1, x='sales', hue='language')
plt.show()
```

[image: график Python]

Код на R:

```
language <- factor(df1$language)
lang_levels <- unique(languages)
sales <- df1$sales

cdplot(languages ~ sales, ylevels = lang_levels)
```

[image: график R]

Насколько я понимаю, проблема связана с особенностями вычисления плотностей: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69518775/what-is-the-difference-between-the-density-function-in-python-and-in-r

Подскажите, что исправить, чтобы сделать графики более похожими? Были попытки исключать выбросы, изменять диапазоны значений и величину сглаживания кривой, но они ни к чему не привели.

---

UPD:

Stripplot на Python:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Stripchart на R:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ограничить диапазон значений от минимума до 75:
Python:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

R:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы уверены, что данные одинаковые? Судя по первому графику по нескольким языкам есть много продаж по 150 экземпляров, а судя по второму - между 120 и 160 экземплярами полный разрыв, нет ни одной продажи. Это не могут быть одни и те же данные. Для начала возьмите один какой-то язык и посмотрите по нему данные в обоих вариантах, и постройте какой-нибудь `histplot` или `scatterplot` и там и там. Я вижу, что данные у вас просто разные. Где-то на подготовке данных вы что-то сделали по-разному.

Comment: @CrazyElf Данные точно правильные. У меня в том числе построены stripplot и boxplot для каждого из языков и они абсолютно идентичны. Возможно, проблема заключается в том, что данные основная часть данных находится левее 100, а справа находятся 2 выброса со значением 200 (так как это книги на английском и французском соответственно, график на R кажется более правильным). Но даже если строить графики, например, только до 75, разница всё равно остаётся (хотя и становится меньше).

Comment: Кстати, что такое `languages ~ sales`? Я `R` вообще не знаю, конструкция выглядит непонятной, сам догадаться не могу )

Comment: @CrazyElf Я тоже не специалист в R, а только учусь) Насколько я понимаю, эта конструкция используется, чтобы показать зависимость между величинами на графике (слева от «~» y(x), справа - x)

Comment: Хм, загадочно. Я не очень понимаю, на что влияет параметр `multiple=` у `seaborn`, ну и я бы попробовал другие параметры поменять, может `kind` другой. Странно, что `kde` такой получается, если там нет точек в том месте вообще.

Comment: @CrazyElf `displot()` строит либо `histplot()`, либо `kdeplot()`, либо `ecdfplot()` в зависимости от значения `kind`. А `multiple=‘fill’` это уже из `kdeplot()`, именно тот внешний вид графика, который нужен

Comment: Сделайте *воспроизводимый* пример, не видя данные и полный код, ошибку найти невозможно.

Comment: Ошибки может быть и нет, скорее сам тип графика выбран неправильно. Что делает `multiple="fill"`: Normalize the stacked distribution at each value in the grid. В данном случае на половине диапазона "нормализовывать" приходится отсутствие значений, поэтому такие странные графики получаются.
`sns.kdeplot()` с параметрами по умолчанию лучше нарисует, на R используйте ggplot2 и `geom_density()`.